# Import/hack classic search template with zones into modern communication site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

I created a classic SharePoint page in a modern communications site for search with refiners. I have my classic search box, results, and refiner web parts wired up and they work just fine, which was surprising. You would think if the functionality was still there to do this, and all that was needed was a page template, they could have gotten around to providing one within the past couple years.

I am able to refine results pulled from all libraries across the site and subsites based on structured list driven metadata, instead of the goofy google-like tagging they seem to be pushing. Awesome. The problem is it looks terrible because I'm using tables to place these web parts, and the left nav pane won't go away.

Is there a way to import or hack a modern comm site so I can install the classic search template that has the proper navigation and main zones for search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround to the workaround was to create a classic basic search subsite which has the proper page templates and web zones, and functions nicely on modern sites and comm sites. I do however get artifacts above the logo now...

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to import or hack a modern comm site.

SharePoint online modern site doesn't support add custom code.

Besides, i suggest you to use the classical page to use the search template.

Comment: I would like to use a classical page search template, but I can’t successfully create it, or import it, on a modern site.

Comment: My workaround would have been to create a classic enterprise search subsite, which has by default the results.aspx page with proper webzones for refiners and main, but this requires SharePoint Server Publishing which isn't available on modern comm sites, and creates issues on modern team sites.